# Blob to image conversion

Tags: objective-c

I am fetching result by fire a transaction but by the transaction one result is coming as blob attributes, that is image, I want to change that blob attribute to image 
I wrote code for that "icon" is the key for fetch the image from transaction,
so please help me check this,
image is printing nil,
why?

```
NSString *inputString = [[[self formModel] attributeAsString:@"icon"] description];

NSLog(@"icon is %@",[[self formModel] attributeAsString:@"icon"]);

NSLog(@"inputstring is %@",inputString);
//NSImage *image = [NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[[self formModel] attributeAsString:@"icon"]];
//NSLog(@"image is %@",image);

NSArray *words = [inputString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

NSLog(@"words is %@",words);

NSArray *sizes = [words valueForKey:@"length"];
int sizeOfBytes = 0;
for (NSNumber *size in sizes) {
    sizeOfBytes += [size intValue]/2;
}
int bytes[sizeOfBytes];
int counts = 0;
for (NSString *word in words) {
    // convert each word from string to int
    NSMutableString *ostr = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:[word length]];
    while ([word length] > 0) {
        [ostr appendFormat:@"%@", [word substringFromIndex:[word length] - 2]];
        word = [word substringToIndex:[word length] - 2];
    }

    NSScanner *scaner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:ostr];
    unsigned int val;
    [scaner scanHexInt:&val];
    bytes[counts] = val;
    counts++;
}
// get NSData form c array
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:bytes length:sizeOfBytes];
NSLog(@"My NSDATA  %@",data);
NSImage *Image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithData:data];
```

Answer (score 1):

Never use the output of `description` to do processing. There is no guarantee of its format. What format is your original "blob" in and how was it generated? Your code suggests it might be an `NSData` or it might be an `NSKeyArchiver`. Both of these easily convert to `NSData`. You never need to do this by hand by converting to a string.